# Showing only uppercase text as labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.14

Using QGIS 2.14 and see there is now rule based labelling. I wish to show labels of towns that have capital letters (eg CRAWLEY) and not show the labels of towns with lowercase letters (eg Faygate)

The attribute table does not distinguish the different towns apart from their name. Is there a way of doing this ?

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You don't really need rule-based styling for this.

1. Select the **Show labels for this layer** option (or rule-based if you prefer) and click the *Expression* icon and go to the *Function Editor* as shown below.

   [image: Function editor]
2. Create a new file (or edit an existing one) and enter the following:

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
   def func(value, feature, parent):
       if value.isupper():
           return value
   ```
3. Click *Load* then go to the *Expression* tab and type the following:

   ```
   func("fieldName")
   ```
4. Then *Apply* all changes. Your labels should now only contain those which are all capital letters.

---

**Example**:

Before running the function:

[image: Before function]

After running the function:

[image: After function]

Comment: Instead of using a custom python function here you could also use the inbuilt expression `"fieldName"=upper("fieldName")`

Comment: @ndawson - Well that's a very handy function, thank you! Although your expression only returns a boolean, you could instead use `if("fieldName" = upper("fieldName"), "fieldName", '')`. Either way, I think you should post it as an **answer** ;)